# Python boto Amazon RDS error: KMSKeyNotAccessibleFault

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, boto3

I am trying to create an Amazon RDS database from a snapshot but I'm getting this error:

> botocore.errorfactory.KMSKeyNotAccessibleFault: An error occurred (KMSKeyNotAccessibleFault) when calling the RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot operation: The specified KMS key [arn:aws:kms:ap-southeast-2:ddddddddd] does not exist, is not enabled or you do not have permissions to access it.

I am not sure which permissions are needed for my Jenkins job to run this task. Is it just a read-only IAM policy?

Comment: Are there any KMS permissions associated with the IAM User that is trying to run the Restore command?

Comment: I added "AWSKeyManagementServicePowerUser" to the role but still no luck..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to IAM Console, choose Encryption Keys menu on the left side bar

Choose the region from the drop down menu (just below the "Create Key" button)

Search for the the mentioned key and see if exists.

If it does not exist, you can never recover back the RDS instance from the snapshot.
If exists,

1. See whether the status is Enabled for the Key. If not, select the checkbox and Choose "Actions -> Enable"
2. Click on it. Under "Key Policy" -> "Key Users", add your IAM user
   and you will be able to restore RDS instance from Snapshot.

Comment: 1. I tried adding my role to the "Key Users" but get this error 
"Policy contains a statement with one or more invalid principals" 

2. I also tried adding this policy to the role but have the same issue. "AWSKeyManagementServicePowerUser"

Comment: Ok, search for "Switch to default view" and click it. It will switch you out from policy view to default view where you can just add users in console instead of chaning the policy. Both will have same effect.

Answer (score 5):

Above answer is correct, but if you're still getting errors try adding this to the key policy:

```
...
"Action": [
    "kms:CreateGrant",
    "kms:ListGrants",
    "kms:RevokeGrant"
],
"Resource": "*",
"Condition": {"Bool": {"kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"}}
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html

Comment: This helped me. I had kms:encrypt/decrypt/reencrypt/generatedatakey/describekey, but I was missing the 3 mentioned above.